# Is there an easy way to change the parent of a record in google app engine datstore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Given

```
class Category(db.Model):
   name = db.Stringproperty()
```

Say I have a nested hierarchy

```
-root
 |-a
 | |-b
 |   |-c
 |-x
   |-y
     |-z1
     |-z2
```

where `a`'s parent is `root`, `b`'s parent is `a`, `c`'s parent is `b` etc.

Is there a simple way by which I could move node `y` from `x` to `b` such that `z1` and `z2` continue to remain children of `y`:

```
-root
 |-a
 | |-b
 |   |-c
 |   |-y
 |     |-z1
 |     |-z2
 |-x
```

That would mean I simply change `y`'s parent.

However, if that is not possible than it would require

1. creating a new record `ny = Category(parent=b, name=y)` and
2. recursively for each child of `y` creating a new record that has `ny` as a parent and
3. than deleting `y` and its children.

Comment: Good question +1.  Would somebody please edit the question to properly format the code in the second paragraph?  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parent relationship is encoded in an entity's key, and the key is immutable once created, so no, you can't change the key of an existing entity. In order to do so, you need to reinsert all the relevant items with new keys.